# Problema Xcode 10 programar App lector PDF

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

Quería saber si me podéis ayudar con este problema. Estoy creando una app lector de Pdf pero me da un error por el cual no sé avanzar. 
"Value of type 'ViewController2' has no member 'nombrePdfRecibido'
El error es este y no sé a qué puede ser debido.

Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No existe o no es publica la variable nombrePdfRecibido, asegurate de que exista y sea accesible

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, necesitamos ver el código de ambos ViewControllers, y recuerda ponerlos como texto no como imagenes

Comment: Sin Problema, añado ambas pantallas de ViewController.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dGmwjU
https://ibb.co/k72rJp